# Два слушателя onClickListener на одну кнопку

Tags: android, setonclicklistener

В зависимости от наличия файлов в папке кнопка меняет свой текст "Читать/Загрузить". Если файлы на месте - сразу setText "Читать" и пошли в другую activity. Если файлов нет - setText "Загрузить" и грузим файлы. Потом меняем надпись на "Читать". Но при повторном нажатии обработчик снова запускает загрузку файлов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать. Вот код:

```
    if(numbFiles == 0) {

        buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonDownload);
        /**
         * Загрузим json с url файлов книги
         */

        Thread jsDownload = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BookLoader();
            }
        });
        jsDownload.start(); // запустили поток 1

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /**
         * Обрабатываем нажатие кнопки "Загрузить" и грузим файлы книги
         */

        buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String fileListB = "list_" + "book_" + bookId + ".json";
                        String jsReadFile = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileListB);
                        Log.d(TAG, jsReadFile);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Book book = gson.fromJson(jsReadFile, Book.class);
                        List<String> pages = book.getPageUrl();
                        String[] urlsPages = pages.toArray(new String[0]);
                        DownloadFilesBook(urlsPages);
                    }
                });
                mThread.start(); // запустили поток 2
                buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
            }
        });
    } else {
        buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
        buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NextActivity();
            }
        });
```

Comment: А где вы numbFiles меняете?

Comment: это счетчик файлов в папке, он при запуске активности сразу срабатывает

Comment: и нигде никогда не меняется. у вас всегда будет первый обработчик работать.

Comment: нет, не так, все меняется но нужно возвращаться на предыдущую активити

Comment: Но я понял, Вы предлагаете плюсовать счётчик. Тогда нужно мне все обернуть циклом. Попробую

Answer (score 0):

Решением оказалось вставка кода слушателя на чтение после запуска потока №2:

```
                buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String fileListB = "list_" + "book_" + bookId + ".json";
                                String jsReadFile = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileListB);
                                Log.d(TAG, jsReadFile);
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                Book book = gson.fromJson(jsReadFile, Book.class);
                                List<String> pages = book.getPageUrl();
                                String[] urlsPages = pages.toArray(new String[0]);
                                DownloadFilesBook(urlsPages);
                            }
                        });
                        mThread.start(); // запустили поток 2
                        buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
                        buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                NextActivity();
                            }
                        });


                    }
                });
            } else {
                buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
                buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        NextActivity();
                    }
                });
```